# How to parent the end of a bone to the middle of another?

Tags: rigging

I have been through many hours of youtube tutorials and still am stuck creating a mechanism rig. I'd like the end of one bone to be parented to the middle of another. See video for details... https://youtu.be/lBbqpHNukQ4

I understand parenting and bones with character rigging, but with mechanisms I parent bones to one another and I don't get the result I am looking for. There seems to be very little mechanism rigging tutorials as everything is geared towards character rigging. Would really appreciate some help with this!

---

I used two ik constraints as shown in the following video and now its working 100% correctly. youtu.be/XbEvTEXeXLc

Answer (score 1):

You can add a *"stretch to"* constraint to the bone:

[image]

Bone.002 has a constraint on the armature that makes it stretch to Bone.001.

The head/tail ratio is 0.5, so it is at the middle.

Original length is the length of Bone.002 when in rest position (edit mode length).

If you want Bone.002 point to without stretching, use a track to constraint instead (same principle):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, lemon. That's very close, but I need bone.002 to be of a fixed length and not stretchy. How would I do that?

Comment: You can use a track to constraint instead. Same principle

Comment: Thanks again. I tried that and it now is fixed which is great but the problem is that bone.002 goes straight through bone.001 and I need it to stay attached... like this https://youtu.be/myj_1HFFvU4

Comment: oh... ok.. you want the head to be attached to the middle of Bone.001 (not its tail)? I've understood the opposite from the first video...

Comment: I think I might have solved it. I used a "track to" constraint like you said, then I created an empty at the head of bone.002 and parented the empty to bone.002. Then I created a track to constraint for bone.001 with the empty as the target.

Comment: ok... that seems to confirm I've really misundertood what you wanted... but great if it works as you expect.

Comment: There are issues that happen with using the empties as targets. In some positions the rig jumps all over the place. I've been looking for a few hours for a tutorial that covers the fundamentals of mechanism rigging. I've found a few good advanced ones but I still don't fully understand the fundamentals well enough to achieve what I want. Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: @TimBrennan, Could you add some pictures describing the cinematic you want? Something where you indicate key positions of the bones, done manually.

Comment: https://youtu.be/O5RZHS0bYnA

Comment: Is that what you want? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/npkbBWoq/

Comment: Thank you for sending the file. It is much more robust, but I need the two vertical bones to be slightly different lengths so there is a gradual tipping action on the horizontal bone. I am hoping to experiment with different lengths and positions of the vertical bones to see what tipping motion is possible for the horizontal bone. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think that's possible only under some angle limits for the main bone. If you push the angle above them, constraints will be relaxed. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/KM6SVBP2/ . May give a try to rigid body constraints, instead. Will give a look when possible but don't know that very well.

Comment: I have a feeling that a IK constraint with a pole target might be the answer, but I have yet to find a tutorial that explains it in a way that I can apply to my situation.

Comment: I used two ik constraints as shown in the following video and now its working 100% correctly. https://youtu.be/XbEvTEXeXLc